# How to print the value of an array without knowing the name of the index value

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach($streams as $stream){
  parse_str($stream,$data);
  }
```

I don't know the value of the index or key of the array $data, as i have parsed value into it. I want to know how can we print the all the values in the array without knowing the value of the key.

Comment: What do you mean by _the_ index or _the_ key of the array? There are usually several, so without knowing what you want you cannot pick something specific. You can only access _all_ keys or values for example by iterating over the array.

Comment: @FrayneKonok echoing $stream wont echo the decoded parsed data

Comment: @arkascha he wanted to print the whole array so we can used the implode function

Comment: Whatever you mean by "the whole array"... Have a try with `echo print_r($data, true);`

Comment: every value of the key in the array so it can be printed using the implode function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the php implode function for printing the value of the array

```
foreach($streams as $stream){
 parse_str($stream,$data);
echo implode(" ",$data). '<br>';
}
```